# How to add a vertical panel and use it as a toggler in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I have this **sideBar** that shows up when clicking on **"btn1"** button. So instead of having a button I would like to have a **vertical bar** with the same title. Basically I would like to accomplish this:

[**Expected Result**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-xx14yf?file=app%2Ftest.component.css)

**Below** is what my code looks like so far. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-eyhyan?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<button (click)="openTab()">btn1</button>
<p-sidebar [modal]="false" class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="opened" 
   position="left" [showCloseIcon]="true" autoZIndex="true" 
   baseZIndex="99999">
   This is the Title
</p-sidebar>
```

Comment: If the expected result link you provided is what you're looking for, what's wrong with adopting the code there? That's the whole point of someone sharing it with the world. And the code you provided doesn't identify an issue trying to get it to work, you're basically just asking someone to code it for you, which again, is in the link you provided?

Comment: The first example uses Flex and I don't need that. I only want to use the custom p-sidebar primeng component rather than creating it from scratch like I did on my first example.

Comment: If you're restricted to primeng solution then you won't be able to use a sidebar without going against the libraries standards @progx According to their [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/sidebar) *Sidebar is a panel component displayed as an **overlay*** You don't need an element with 'sidebar' in the title for it to behave like one.

Comment: I want to customize it so I can have a vertical bar and when I click on it the sideBar will show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your existing [DEMO stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-eyhyan?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) link here - replace the complete TS, HTML & CSS in the stackblitz with the 3 codes below OR [Open this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzmqk6)

replace your existing **app.component.html** with the following:

```
<!-- <button (click)="openTab()">btn1</button> -->
<p-sidebar [modal]="false" class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="opened" position="left" [showCloseIcon]="false" autoZIndex="true" baseZIndex="99999">
  <div id="panelHeader" (click)='menuPanelClose()'> Click here to close menu </div>
  <div id="panelBody"> This is the Title ... <br/> background panel visibility is {{togglePanel}} </div>
</p-sidebar>

<div id='menuToggler' ng-if="togglePanel == true"  (click)="panelClick()">
  This is toggle Panel
</div>
```

replace your existing **app.component.css** with the following:

```
#panelHeader{width: 100%; height:10vh; background: lightpink;}
#panelBody { background:lightcyan; height:90vh;}
#menuToggler{writing-mode: vertical-lr;background: lightgreen;width: 40px;padding: 10px;height: 100%;left: 0;position: absolute;top: 0;font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;font-size: 14px;}
```

replace your existing **app.component.ts** with the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SidebarModule} from 'primeng/sidebar';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  opened = false;
  togglePanel:boolean = true;


  openTab() {
    this.opened = true;
  }

  panelClick(){
    this.opened = true;
    this.togglePanel = false;
  }

  menuPanelClose(){
    this.opened = false;
    this.togglePanel = true;
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**: questioner didn't want another `<p-sidebar>` for the menu-toggler

**UPDATE 2**: posting a new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzmqk6) on questioner's request

Comment: I would prefer to work with the same sideBar and not create another <p-sidebar> to toggle

Comment: You added a preference which was not part of the original question and then you down voted the answer (which was working) because of it?

Comment: I didn't down vote it bro. Also, I don't see a need of adding an extra <p-sidebar>. I would like to use only <p-sidebar> just like I have it on my Demo.

Comment: using a normal div to replace this `<p-sidebar>` would work for you ?

Comment: Can you share a live demo on what you're proposing? Thanks

Comment: @progx kindly check the live stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzmqk6

Comment: Thank you for your input bro!

Comment: Thanks, my very first bounty :) ... Wish you the best in your endeavors...